# Не могу перенести Laravel на хостинг

Tags: laravel, хостинг

Пытаюсь закинуть проект Laravel на хостинг 
Выбивает:

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.51 (Unix) Server at danilkkl.beget.tech Port 80

Структура FTP 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура моего проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки в Laravel

Comment: А если в url добавить public (`danilkkl.beget.tech/public`) - работает? И нет смысла добавлять бесполезные скриншоты, лучше бы показали настройки хоста

Comment: @Danil А вы прикрепили к домену папку?

Comment: @Arcadiy Если я правильно Вас понял, то да

Comment: @InDevX Нет, все равно не работает

Comment: @Danil Покажите настройки хоста и удалите все добавленные скрины - они бесполезны

Answer (score 0):

APP_URL - Убери в конце слеш (/)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно прописать в конфиге nginx путь до public если используется vds, если обычный хостинг то создайте файл .htaccess и впишите туда

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```